# Matlab: How to print " ' " character

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create the following string:

```
javaaddpath ('C:\MatlabUserLib\ParforProgMonv2')
```

However, I could only do the following

```
command = sprintf('%s ', varargin{1}, '(', varargin{2}, ')');
```

and that gives me:

```
javaaddpath ( C:\MatlabUserLib\ParforProgMonv2 )
```

---

UPDATE:
Based on [Dan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137124/1011724), I used the following:

```
command = sprintf('%s', varargin{1}, '(', '''', varargin{2}, '''', ')')
```

Comment: You don't really need to add what you used to your question, it's simpler to just accept the answer ;)

Comment: In cases that you have to deal with that symbol in multiple places it is easier to have a variable to contain it `o='''';` and use `o` when you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two single quotation marks. See the docs for [formatting strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html), btw this concept is known as an [escape character](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Escape_character) (to help you google such things in the future).

```
command = sprintf('%s ', varargin{1}, '(''', varargin{2}, ''')')
```

Although I think you might prefer

```
command = sprintf('%s (''%s'')', varargin{1}, varargin{2})
```

or if you have no other `varargin`s (which I guess is very unlikely but anyway)

```
command = sprintf('%s (''%s'')', varargin{:})
```

Comment: Extra space is being created: javaaddpath ( ' C:\MatlabUserLib\ParforProgMonv2 ' )  . How could I kill these extra space?

Comment: @DushyantKumar Use my second suggestion (which is a better way to do it in general). Your extra space comes from the fact that you put a space character after your `%s` i.e. `'%s '`, which will thus put a space after each string in the arguments that follow.

Comment: Thanks for the vocabulary lesson I didn't know these were called escape characters

Comment: @Dan - If you'd like to, I've made a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss MATLAB things... and for things that can't normally fit into the span of a comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - Visit whenever you've got time!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways around this. First you could declare your path as a string variable then pass the string to your command, eg,

```
path = 'my/path'
javaaddpath (path)
```

Or you can use [special characters](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z6xa) to insert things like a single quote or a new line character, so for a single quote,

EDIT: wrong display command as pointed out by Dan below

```
myString = '" Hi there! "' 
disp(myString)
```

Comment: I don't think you want `print` in Matlab... the `'''` is correct though

Comment: ahh yes of course, I blame being recently converted to Python :D